# Java call interface method without creating a new instance

Tags: java, methods, interface, instance

interfaces are the only type of classes which any class can extend. But unfortunately java developers(?) removed the ability to override an interface static method. Anyone know how can I call an interface method without creating a new instance of the class extending it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java interface static method helps us in providing security by **not allowing** implementation classes to override them. We **can't define interface static method** for Object class methods, we will get compiler error as “This static method cannot hide the instance method from Object”.

In order to call an interface method from a Java program, the program must **first instantiate the interface** implementation program. A method can then be called using the implementation object.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are not classes per se, they are Abstract Types.
In Java 8, the "small brained" Oracle developers you mention do allow both `default` and `static` types in interfaces. Look at this example. from [JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method)

**1. Default Types**

```
public interface Interface1 {

    void method1(String str);

    default void log(String str){
        System.out.println("I1 logging::"+str);
    }
}
```

The interface has a default type that doesnt need to be overriden/re-implemented when being called by a class.

**1b. Default Conflicts**
Assume you have Two Interfaces. the one shown in part 1, and the following:

```
public interface Interface2 {   
    default void log(String str){
        System.out.println("I2 logging::"+str);
    }
}
```

If you implement both of these interfaces in a class e.g.

```
    public class MyClass implements Interface1, Interface2 {
      ...//other implementations.
    @Override
    //Must override/provide implementation to avoid ambiguity
    public void log(String str){
        System.out.println("MyClass logging::"+str);
        Interface1.print("abc");
    }
}
```

**You will have to provide an implementation** so as to avoid conflict from both implemented interfaces.

**2. Static Types**
As you've asked, you can have static methods in interfaces. Look at this sample from the same [article](https://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method)

```
public interface MyData {

    default void print(String str) {
        if (!isNull(str))
            System.out.println("MyData Print::" + str);
    }

    static boolean isNull(String str) {
        System.out.println("Interface Null Check");

        return str == null ? true : "".equals(str) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

The only difference between the default and statics is that you **cannot override** static methods. This is a core Java principle. So this static method will stay as is in the class that implements this interface.

Alot can be found from the [JournalDev website](https://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method)